# Wrapping hunspell to stem a large number of words efficiently?

Tags: bash, stemming, hunspell

I have written a script for stemming English words, it does a decent job but it takes forever when I use it on big files, which have more than 1000 words, one per line. Are there ways to speed it up? Maybe a different approach altogether? Different programming language? Different stemmer?

```
file=$1
while read -r a
do
b="$(echo "$a" | hunspell -s -d en_US | wc -l)"
if [[ "$b" -eq 2 ]]
 then
   g="$(echo "$a" | hunspell -s -d en_US | wc -w)"
   if [[ "$g" -eq 1 ]]
    then
     echo "$a" | hunspell -s -d en_US | awk 'FNR==1 {print $1}'
    else
     echo "$a" | hunspell -s -d en_US | awk 'FNR==1 {print $2}'
   fi
 else
   if [[ "$a" == *ing ]] || [[ "$a" == *ed ]]
     then
       echo "$a" | hunspell -s -d en_US | awk 'FNR==2 {print $2}'
     else
       echo "$a" | hunspell -s -d en_US | awk 'FNR==1 {print $1}'
   fi
fi
done < "$file"
```

Here's an example of what it does.

input file

```
cliché
womb
range
strain
fiddle
coup
earnest
touched
gave
dazzling
blindfolded
stagger
buying
insignia
```

output

```
cliché
womb
range
strain
fiddle
coup
earnest
touch
give
dazzle
blindfold
stagger
buy
insignia
```

---

## How it works

If you run `hunspell -s -d en_US word`, it can give you different results depending on a word. Options, and actions to take, follow:

- One line with one word (print that word)
- One line with two words (print second word)
- Two lines with two words; ends with "ing" or "ed" (print second word on second line)
- Two lines with two words; not ending with "ing" or "ed" (print first word on first line)

Comment: Don't Repeat Yourself. You run `echo "$a" | hunspell -s -d en_US` two or three times for each word. Don't do that. Just do it once and save it. bash also isn't the fastest at running through large files like this. Using something else (even just awk) might be much faster. If `hunspell` can operate in a streaming mode that you can read from reliably you could do that.

Comment: It's not the `if`s slowing your scripts; it's all the subshells you're putting in your conditions.

Comment: ...and **definitely** follow Etan's suggestion, invoking `hunspell` fewer times and streaming its output.

Comment: You could run `if [[ "$a" == *ing ]] || [[ "$a" == *ed ]]; then :; fi` literally a thousand times in the execution time needed to run just one `echo "$a" | hunspell -s -d en_US | awk 'FNR==1 {print $1}'`. Pipelines are expensive; spinning up external tools is expensive! Learn to use native bash string manipulation, too.

Comment: Also, if this code works and you just need help making it better then this question is a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com than this site.

Comment: ...see BashFAQ #001, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001, for the idiom used in my answer to read each line of hunspell's output into a series of variables.

Comment: ...BTW, it's very nonobvious what cases most of the branches in this script are intended to handle. Comments would be helpful, or *at minimum* test data selected to actually exercise all the logic provided.

Comment: Hmm. I can't get *quite* the same output -- `hunspell -s -d en_US <<<gave` doesn't have `give` anywhere in its output at all for me. Other than that, though, what I'm currently getting is 100% identical.

Comment: BTW, in your original script you have `echo "$a" | hunspell -s -d en_US | awk 'FNR==1 {print $1}'` for the last condition, but the way I read your desired logic, shouldn't that be `echo "$a" | hunspell -s -d en_US | awk 'FNR==1 {print $2}'`?

Comment: Right, I was mistaken in my description but it doesn't matter because if the output is more than one line the words on first line are always the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following emits the exact same output (but for changing `gave` to `give`, which my `hunspell` appears not to have in its dictionary) -- and far, far faster:

```
last_word=; stems=( )
while read -r word stem _; do
  if [[ $word ]]; then
    last_word=$word
    [[ $stem ]] && stems+=( "$stem" )
  else
    if (( ${#stems[@]} == 0 )); then
      printf '%s\n' "$last_word"        # no stems available; print input word
    elif (( ${#stems[@]} == 1 )); then
      printf '%s\n' "${stems[0]}"       # found one stem; print it.
    else
      case $last_word in
        *ing|*ed) printf '%s\n' "${stems[1]}" ;; # "ing" or "ed": print the 2nd stem
        *)        printf '%s\n' "${stems[0]}" ;; # otherwise: print the 1st stem
      esac
    fi
    stems=( )
  fi
done < <(hunspell -s -d en_US <"$1")
```

Note that this runs `hunspell` **only once for the whole file**, not once per word; it's restarting `hunspell` over and over, not anything to do with bash, where your script is spending all its time.

Comment: How do I run it? line 5: file: No such file or directory

Comment: `file` is the name of your input file. Make it `$1` if you like.

Comment: Since the `while` loop doesn't set any variables needed by the shell once the loop exits, it's probably simpler to pipe the output of `hunspell` to the loop instead of redirecting input from a process substitution.

Comment: It gives different results. Sorry, my post was a little misleading at the end it's a one-column input file and output is also one column.

Comment: Yes, that's misleading indeed. Then just `echo "$first_root"` -- or, better, `printf '%s\n' "$first_root"`.

Comment: @chepner, *shrug*. I tend to consider this the better practice -- means someone can put code with side effects on shell state in place later without surprises. Personal taste, to be sure.

Comment: And all those conditions are necessary  to eliminate duplicates, which otherwise will appear. For instance  "dazzling, dazzle" and "blindfolded, blindfold" like in your solution.

Comment: Ahh! So you want only the first word after any newline. Now, **that's** a helpful description.

Comment: Updated appropriately. Still only one pass, still no crap with piping to `wc` or `awk`.

Comment: It depends, you see, it can be 4 different ways hence the conditions.

Comment: What can be four different ways? You still haven't added comments to your original code.

Comment: ...or an English-language description of the intended logic either.

Comment: If you run hunspell -s -d en_US word, it can give you different results depending on a word, it can be one line with one word, one line with two words, two lines with two words each. If it just one word then I print that word, if it one line with two words then I print second word, if it two lines with two words then I print second word on the second line...

Comment: ...but I print second word on the second line if the word doesn't end with an ing or ed affix then I print second word on the first line.

Comment: Edit that into the question -- that way it'll help anyone else who wants to try to answer without them needing to read this saga.

Comment: It's almost perfect, but it prints a blank line if the output equals just one word, for example "cliché".

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Literally, I don't get a blank line in that case.

Comment: BTW, feel free to ask questions about how this works, if any part is unclear.

Comment: I don't really understand most of it so a description would be helpful I have some more slow scripts using pipelines, maybe I could modify them myself.

Comment: I'm sorry -- if you can't identify a specific question, I don't have the time for a general description of everything it does. BashFAQ #1, at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001, is a good place to start.